# #{javax.enterprise.context.conversation.id} is always empty

Tags: jsf-2, cdi, el, weld, conversation-scope

I'm using this expression on my template.xhtml

```
<h:outputText value="Conversation [#{javax.enterprise.context.conversation.id}]"/>
```

But when I execute the code the output is always

> Conversation [].

Why is no rendering the returning value for this expression?

I'm using NetBeans 8, Glassfish 4.1, JSF 2.2 (Mojarra) on Windows 8.1

Comment: Do you invoke a `@ConversationScoped` bean on this page? If yes, please add the code.

Comment: I did not invoke anything with @ConverstaionScoped, but Other variables fails too, I mean all between #{}

Comment: conversation exists only if you have a `@ConversationScoped bean` otherwise, it does not make sense

Comment: did you call `begin()` on your `Conversation` somewhere?